# adding a column based on other values

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with millions of rows and three columns labeled Keywords, Impressions, Clicks. I'd like to add a column with values depending on the evaluation of this function:

```
isType <- function(Impressions, Clicks)
{ 
if (Impressions >= 1 & Clicks >= 1){return("HasClicks")} else if (Impressions >=1 & Clicks == 0){return("NoClicks")} else {return("ZeroImp")}
}
```

so far so good. I then try this to create the column but 1) it takes for ever and 2) it marks all the rows has "HasClicks" even the ones where it shouldn't.

```
# Creates a dataframe
Type <- data.frame()
# Loops until last row and store it in data.frame
for (i in c(1:dim(Mydf)[1])) {Type <- rbind(Type,isType(Mydf$Impressions[i], Mydf$Clicks[i]))}
# Add the column to Mydf
Mydf <- transform(Mydf, Type = Type)
```

input data:

Keywords,Impressions,Clicks
"Hello",0,0
"World",1,0
"R",34,23

Wanted output:

Keywords,Impressions,Clicks,Type
"Hello",0,0,"ZeroImp"
"World",1,0,"NoClicks"
"R",34,23,"HasClicks"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Building on Joshua's solution, I find it cleaner to generate Type in a single shot (note however that this presumes Clicks >= 0...)

```
Mydf$Type = ifelse(Mydf$Impressions >= 1,
    ifelse(Mydf$Clicks >= 1, 'HasClicks', 'NoClicks'), 'ZeroImp')
```

Comment: Thank you! I got to the same conclusion that ifelse needed to be used. I'm too new to R to understand why but thanks!

Comment: @datayoda: `if()` allows only a single condition. I.e. it allows, or uses, only a single TRUE or FALSE. In your code, you were getting many TRUE/FALSE values and only the first of which would be used. In an `if()` clause, you also shouldn't use `&` as that is vectorised and does the comparison for each element of the associated vectors. `&&` is for comparing single values. Compare: `runif(10) > 0.5 & runif(10) > 0.3` with `runif(10) > 0.5 && runif(10) > 0.3`. If one or more of the first version is FALSE, the second (`&&`) version will return an overall FALSE. `ifelse` is a vectorised `if`.

Answer (score 3):

First, the if/else block in your function will return the warning:

> Warning message:
>   In if (1:2 > 2:3) TRUE else FALSE :
>   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

which explains why it all the rows are the same.

Second, you should allocate your data.frame and fill in the elements rather than repeatedly combining objects together.  I imagine this is causing your long run-times.

EDIT: My shared code.  I'd love for someone to provide a more elegant solution.

```
Mydf <- data.frame(
  Keywords = sample(c("Hello","World","R"),20,TRUE),
  Impressions = sample(0:3,20,TRUE),
  Clicks = sample(0:3,20,TRUE) )

Mydf$Type <- "ZeroImp"
Mydf$Type <- ifelse(Mydf$Impressions >= 1 & Mydf$Clicks >= 1,
  "HasClicks", Mydf$Type)
Mydf$Type <- ifelse(Mydf$Impressions >= 1 & Mydf$Clicks == 0,
  "NoClicks", Mydf$Type)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where arithmetic can be cleaner and most likely faster than nested `ifelse` statements.

Again building on Joshua's solution:

```
Mydf$Type <- factor(with(Mydf, (Impressions>=1)*2 + (Clicks>=1)*1),
                    levels=1:3, labels=c("ZeroImp","NoClicks","HasClicks"))
```