# Add a column with function result based on other columns

Tags: r, dataframe, calculated-columns

I've the following data frame:

```
Latitude , Longitude, Altitude
44.388401, 8.433392 , 463.000000
44.388571, 8.434575 , 471.000000
44.388740, 8.435758 , 507.000000
44.388910, 8.436941 , 563.000000
44.389079, 8.438123 , 606.000000
44.389249, 8.439306 , 629.000000
44.389418, 8.440489 , 639.000000
44.389588, 8.441672 , 640.000000
44.389757, 8.442854 , 590.000000
44.389927, 8.444037 , 564.000000
44.390096, 8.445220 , 543.000000
44.390265, 8.446403 , 527.000000
44.390435, 8.447585 , 469.000000
```

The first two columns are latitude and longitude (in degrees) and the third column is the altitude. What I want to do is to add a column representing the distance of the observation position from the position of the first observation, something like (distance are not exact, it's just for showing)

```
Latitude , Longitude, Distance , Altitude
44.388401, 8.433392 ,  0.000000, 463.000000
44.388571, 8.434575 , 10.000000, 471.000000
44.388740, 8.435758 , 21.000000, 507.000000
44.388910, 8.436941 , 25,231232, 563.000000
44.389079, 8.438123 , 33,211333, 606.000000
44.389249, 8.439306 , 55,000000, 629.000000
...
```

I know that I can use the function `distm` from library `geosphere`, but the question is: how I can add a column which value is calculated by a function that has as arguments other values of the same observation and values of the first observation?

I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919658/adding-a-column-based-on-other-values), but it allows to calculate new column based on other data of the same observation, not same observation AND first one, like I need.

Answer (score 0):

not sure why the `distm` function was written the way it was, but this should work:

```
   library(dplyr)

# Put the data in a data frame
df <- data.frame(Latitude = c(44.388401,44.388571), Longitude = c(8.433392,8.434575), Altitude =  c(471.000000, 463.000000))

# Extract the two required columns 
start_point <-  df %>% select(Longitude,  Latitude) %>% filter(row_number() == 1)
lat_long <- select(df,  Longitude, Latitude)

# Calculate distance 
df %>% mutate(Distance = distm(lat_long, start_point ))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly then you could use `pmap_dbl` from `purrr`

```r
library(dplyr)
library(geosphere)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate(Distance = pmap_dbl(., ~distm(c(..2, ..1), 
                                       c(Longitude[1], Latitude[1]), 
                                       fun = distHaversine)))
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(Latitude = c(44.388401, 44.388571, 44.38874, 44.38891, 
44.389079, 44.389249, 44.389418, 44.389588, 44.389757, 44.389927, 
44.390096, 44.390265, 44.390435), Longitude = c(8.433392, 8.434575, 
8.435758, 8.436941, 8.438123, 8.439306, 8.440489, 8.441672, 8.442854, 
8.444037, 8.44522, 8.446403, 8.447585), Altitude = c(463, 471, 
507, 563, 606, 629, 639, 640, 590, 564, 543, 527, 469)), .Names = c("Latitude", 
"Longitude", "Altitude"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```